# What is the best bicycle brake system

Tags: brakes

What is the best brake system for bicycles?

Are metal rod brakes good or are cable brakes better?

Comment: Depends on the type of riding you need to do. Coaster brakes are nice for kids cause they can operate them when they might not be able to operate a handbrake, but the increased maintenance cost and difficulty in moving the pedals to starting position among other things don't make them that good for most adults.

Comment: @Batman, i'm using a normal indian Bicycle with metal breaks. but afraid to Ride down from a mountain..

Comment: It is "brakes", not "breaks". Are you talking about rod brakes like in [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_brake#/media/File:Rod_brake.JPG)?

Comment: @Batman, yes, same bike i have & thank you for explaining my wrong spelling

Comment: It depends on what you want to optimize still (and there are many types of brakes which use cables). You can go to sheldonbrown.com and read about different brake systems and come to your conclusion.

Comment: Rocket brakes have the advantage that they work in zero gravity. None of the other options work at all in that situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Best" brake system greatly depends on the type of riding to be done. Trials bike with extremely strong brakes are perfect for hopping around and locking the wheel up instantly, they however would not be so great at trail riding where disc brakes with good modulation are ideal.

From a service and everyday joe stand point, my choice would probably be mechanical disc brakes as they are easy to adjust and service (No bleeding etc) while they also provide ample stopping power if decent quality and are adjusted right. I however use Hydraulic disc brakes as i'm a big fan of the modulation, or ability to slow down quickly without actually locking up the rear wheel unless i want to. But most of the riding i do is on dirt trails.

The main selling point of hydraulic disc brakes is there is very little friction in the system. Where as a cable driven disc brake has friction present in the entire system essentially as the cable slides through its housing. Resulting in a slightly different lever feel and power.

Cantilevers would be my choice for road and commuter use as they are tried and true, they put up with abuse and wet pretty well and they are easy to fix and adjust even on the side of the road with minimal tools.

With that said, i don't think there is a concrete "right" answer to this questions unless it is in regards to a specific riding style or location.

I would not personally want to ride old school rod brakes down a long decent either. Although i have done it plenty of times with V-brakes i would prefer a disc, although many good quality V-brakes have nearly equal stopping power.

So it really comes down to the individual and what they are trying to accomplish.

From [Sheldon Brown](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/brake-choices.html)

> **Rim brakes** are lightest because rims also serve as brake discs. Wheels must be true for rim brakes to work smoothly -- and so, their maintenance also involves wheel maintenance. If rims are wet, rim-brake performance suffers until the brake shoes wipe them dry -- a very serious problem with chromed steel rims, much less a problem with aluminum alloy rims. Rim brakes wear rims, quickly in muddy or sandy conditions. Also see the article about rim brakes -- which links in turn to articles about the several different kinds.
>
> Though **drum brakes** all are very weather-resistant, their performance varies widely. They are common on utility bicycles, because of their weatherproofness, but only a few special drum brakes can avoid overheating on long downgrades. Generally, the larger the drum, the stronger the braking, and the better heat dissipation. A drum brake which is integrated into a hub can suffer contamination from lubricants. If the drum wears out, the hub, and usually the wheel -- must be replaced. These problems do not occur if the drum brake is external to the hub. (Drum brake article is in the works...)
>
> **Disc brakes** dissipate heat better than most drum brakes. Disc brakes have become popular on mountain bikes and are gaining popularity for other bicycles. Because only the discis attached to the wheel, a disc brake easily allows wheel changes. Disc brakes can only be installed on frames with special fittings, and have unique problems, worst among which is that a front disc brake can pull the wheel out of the fork.
>
> **Coaster brakes** are operated by backpedaling, and so can be installed only on the rear wheel. Coaster brakes are the most maintenance-free, and suitable for children with limited hand strength. On a folding or take-apart bicycle, a coaster brake avoids the need for a cable connection. A coaster brake complicates starting and stopping, and prevents the use of toeclips and straps, clipless pedals or derailer gearing. A coaster brake may, however. be incorporated into an internal-gear hub --- but then, except with a two-speed kickback hub, a shifter cable is needed. A coaster brake is OK for utility cycling but unsuitable for speed control on long downhill runs.

Comment: The main advantage of rod brakes is that they don't really need upkeep beyond pad replacements, and if you're in a rural area (esp. 3rd world countries), it's likely the only brake in use on their bicycles. With other things, you don't want to break down beyond the point that you can fix it yourself, since locals will likely not have parts or expertise in it.

Comment: @Batman, you are 100% correct..